# Accessing web.py web server

Tags: python, web.py

I'm trying to run [the tutorial code](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial) for web.py, and everything works fine except when I try to access the web server using a browser it says it can't connect to the server.
Here is the code:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

I run it like this:

```
$ python code.py
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

As far as I can tell, this is exactly what the tutorial says to do, but like I say when I try to access the web server it gives me an error. For example, when I copy the address into firefox it gives me this error:

`Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 0.0.0.0:8080.`

Any ideas of what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can goto:

`http://localhost:8080` in your web-browser!

Simply `0.0.0.0` means open to all incoming 'host's' whereas, you want to connect to your localhost